# authentication filter was called repeatedly

Tags: spring

I setup spring security for my rest apis.  Here is a sample of my rest call, 
    GET: http://localhost:8081/dashboard/epic/data.  When executing, filter, provider and eventual onAuthenticationSuccess are triggered.  Here is the problem, instead of executing the rest url after authentication, it will go back to filter many times.  For the second time, request.getRequestUrl will be http://localhost:8081/dashboard.

Here is my security-context.xml:

```
  <http auto-config='false' authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <intercept-url pattern="dashboard/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" ref="DashboardFilter"></custom-filter>
</http>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="DashboardAuthProvider"></authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="DashboardFilter" class="com.apple.store.dashboard.security.DashboardAuthFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="com.apple.store.dashboard.security.LoginSuccessHandler">


        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="com.apple.store.dashboard.security.DashboardAuthEntryPoint">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="DashboardAuthProvider" class="com.apple.store.dashboard.security.DashboardAuthProvider">  </beans:bean>
```

Here is my filter

```
public class DashboardAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardAuthFilter.class);

    public DashboardAuthFilter() {
        //super("/j_spring_cas_security_check");
        super("/**");
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        logger.debug("Inside DashboardAuthFilter:attemptAuthentication method:");
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth!=null ){
            if (auth.isAuthenticated()){
                logger.debug("Previously authenticated.isAuthenticated=true::: Auth details:" +auth);
                return auth;
            }
        }

        String _username = null;
        String _password = null;


        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(authHeader);
            if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String basic = st.nextToken();

                if (basic.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                    try {
                        String credentials = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(st.nextToken()), "UTF-8");
                        logger.debug("Credentials: " + credentials);
                        int p = credentials.indexOf(":");
                        if (p != -1) {
                             _username = credentials.substring(0, p).trim();
                             _password = credentials.substring(p + 1).trim();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("request url is "+request.getRequestURL());

        Authentication authResult = null;
        try {
            if( org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(_password)) {
                throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("No username:password..");
            }
            String credentials = "NA";

            //String validateCookieDetails = correctAuthentication(AOSCookie, request);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(_username+":"+_password, credentials);
            authResult = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
            logger.debug("Attempted authentication: authResult ::" + authResult.toString());
        } catch (org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException e) {
                logger.error("AttemptAuthentication: Not Authenticated : AuthenticationException ....." + e.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occured during authentication....." + e.getMessage());
        }
        return authResult;
    }
```

Here is my provider:

```
public class DashboardAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardAuthProvider.class);


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.debug("Inside DashboardAuthProvider: authenticate method +authentication=" + authentication);
        Authentication auth =null;
        final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        try{
            String[] principalStrArr = ((String)authentication.getPrincipal()).split(":");
            //Convert the authentication principal object to a map

            if (principalStrArr[0].equals("test1") && principalStrArr[1].equals("test1"))
            {
                String username = principalStrArr[0];
                String password = principalStrArr[1];


                final UserDetails principal = new AccessInfo(username, password, grantedAuths);
                auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);

                logger.info("DashboardAuthProvider auth= " + auth);
            }
            else {
                logger.info("Wrong credential");
                return null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(
                    "Exception occured in DashboardAuthProvider during authentication",
                    e);
        }
        return auth;

    }
```

And here is my onAuthenticationSuccess:

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

    }
```

Comment: Because that is what you configured your filter to do. Your `/**` in the constructor is the URL the filter is listening to to be invoked, that is now every URL, so for every URL this filter is kicking in.

Comment: But I am only invoking one url onetime, http://localhost:8081/dashboard/epic/data.  The filter is still invoked several times before the call returns

Comment: Which is protected, which calls the entry point, which calls the filter, which is protected, which calls the filter, which is protected etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get out of this? How do I configure a url pattern?  I tried dashboard/**, but when I used http://localhost:8081/dashboard/epic/data, the filter is not triggered?

Comment: You don't the filter should apply to a single URL only, the entry point should send you to that URL.